# Does java take time to call a method?

Tags: java, performance, methods, jvm

I was doing some experiments in java, and I've encountered a thing that is bugging me. I have realized that in java, when I use a method instead of direct code, it takes more time to process it.

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long nanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
    int i = foo();
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println("Elapsed Nanoseconds = " + (System.nanoTime() - nanoSeconds));
    nanoSeconds = System.nanoTime();
    int l = 10;
    i = l;
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println("Elapsed Nanoseconds = " + (System.nanoTime() - nanoSeconds));
}

public final static int foo() {
    int i = 10;
    return i;
}
```

It is a simple code divided in two parts. The first one measures the time of foo() and shows the returned value of foo(), and the second part does the same but without calling foo().

The result was the following:

10

Elapsed Nanoseconds = 601582

10

Elapsed Nanoseconds = 49343

So my question is if is there a way to not loose this performance?

Thanks all.

Comment: Its just a curiosity. I dont think that he's benchmarking something. I think that he's asking if there is a way, to decrease the time of method calling in java.

Comment: If he just reverses the order of his measurements, we will be in for a big surprise: now suddenly the "benchmark" will show that inlined code is much slower. But that's just a start, no point in enumerating everything which is wrong with this naïvest of the naïve approaches to benchmarking.

Comment: Use JMH and read about JIT.

Comment: You should check the compiled code. It wouldn't be a surprise if the compiler removes the method `foo` and inlines the returned value instead, in order to optimize the code.

Comment: @Tom You will definitely not see that in the bytecode and OP is a long, long way from being able to generate and understand JITC-produced machine code.

Comment: @Tom it won't; see my answer

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, you were right I inverted and the results were better for the method instead of the direct code. Thanks for the comment I did not know that :)!

Comment: See [my ideone test](http://ideone.com/dWQmaQ) - try changing the `loops` variable from 1000 to 10000

Comment: It's because your first part of the code triggers some one-time initialization code. Also *never* include any I/O in the measurement (such as your `System.out.println`), which will dwarf what you are actually trying to measure by many orders of magnitude).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will not obtain any meaningful benchmark this way.

You don't account for the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).

The **compiler** will not perform any optimization in this regard, apart from very obvious ones; when it sees a method call in the source code, even if this method call always returns the same value, it will generate bytecode which invokes the method; when it sees a constant, it will generate an ldc (load constant) bytecode instruction.

BUT.

Then the JIT kicks in at some point. If it determines that a method call always returns the same result, then it will inline the call. At **runtime**. But this is only done after a certain amount of executions of that code are performed, and it always has a way back if it admits that it has missed at some point (this is backtracking).

And that is but one optimization a good JIT implementation can perform.

You want to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Yud4Q2HEz4). Long story short: with Oracle's JVM, optimization will start to kick in only after a piece of code will be executed 10000 times at least — for some definition of "piece of code".

Comment: Good addition to mention that this is regarding the Oracle JVM - questions like this become vague when you speak of only "Java". Most people also mistakenly include Dalvik/Android in that camp for example.

Comment: @Gimby yup, but then I have never worked with Dalvik; anyway, the JIT is the main reason why when you write Java, what matters is that you write obviously correct code, performance optimization only comes in when you have actual performance problems ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was very useful! I can't watch the video now but I will watch it as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your code measured on JMH:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(Measure.SIZE)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 100, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 200, timeUnit=MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Threads(1)
@Fork(1)
public class Measure
{
  public static final int SIZE = 1;

  @Benchmark public int call() {
    int i = foo();
    return i;
  }

  @Benchmark public int callDisableOptimization() {
    int i = fooDontInline();
    return i;
  }

  @Benchmark public int inline() {
    int i;
    int l = 10;
    i = l;
    return i;
  }

  static int foo() {
    int i = 10;
    return i;
  }

  @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
  static int fooDontInline() {
    int i = 10;
    return i;
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `call` corresponds to your first measurement, a regular call to `foo()`;
- `inline` corresponds to your second measurement, where you inline the logic of `foo()` with no calls involved;
- `callDisableOptimization` is a special twist on the first case, where we used advanced low-level control to disable the automatic inlining by the JVM.

And these are the results:

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Samples  Score   Error  Units
o.s.Measure.call                       avgt        5  1,279 ± 0,114  ns/op
o.s.Measure.inline                     avgt        5  1,289 ± 0,100  ns/op
o.s.Measure.callDisableOptimization    avgt        5  3,167 ± 0,217  ns/op
```

Things to note:

- there is actually no difference at all between your two pieces of code. The JIT-compiler will have an easy time inlining that method call for you, ending up with precisely the same code in both cases;
- the added third case shows just how insignificant the overhead would be even without JIT compiler's inlining: a true method invocation incurs an overhead of less than 2 nanoseconds. Putting this in perspective, a million invocations would add just 2 milliseconds to the overall runtime.

Some comments on your approach to measuring performance on the JVM:

- what you're trying to measure takes around a single *nanosecond*;
- you are including that nanosecond together with a `println` operation, which takes on the order of *microseconds* at least;
- you have not done any warmup at all;
- you have failed to collect a statistically representative sample;
- the time reported by your attempt is 6 *milliseconds* for the first measurement. It is off by a factor of 6 million from the real value;
- the stark difference between your first and second mesauremnts is attributable to one-time initialization code which runs during the first measurement, an entirely irrelevant artefact;
- etc.
- etc.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here but I'm interested in something: how do you _run_ that code? I know about jmh but I have never managed to run it

Comment: You just need some boilerplate `pom.xml`, taken from the JMH homepage.

Comment: OK, that's what I feared; no way to run it via the command line without maven... This hasn't changed since the last time I looked :-(

Comment: Actually, I've checked what the maven build amounts to, there are no special steps. You can easily reproduce all that without Maven, all you'll need to do is download the JMH jar.

Comment: Note that Maven will not infect your computer with a virus, its a useful little tool to have around requiring no installation of any kind - just unpack and go. So I wouldn't know why you need a frowny face when Maven is needed.

Comment: @Gimby I happen to use gradle; also, I don't want to download The World(tm) just to get to run performance tests. Although it has its share of problems as well, at least caliper doesn't require maven to have a working `main()`.

Comment: @fge You don't *need* maven to run JMH, the pom is there for those who regard that as a convenience :-) All you need is the JMH jar and you run its own main class. As for Caliper, it requires you to write the measurement loop, which causes troubles due to loop unrolling and other transformations.

Comment: For future reference, I've checked the above in detail and this is the full story. There are 3 compile/runtime deps: `jmh-core`, `jopt-simple`, and `commons-math3`; and an additional compile-time dep (compile-time annotation processor): `jmh-generator-annprocess`. Still a quite simple setup, easily replicated in gradle, ant, or a plain shell script. It works out-of-the box in Eclipse with basic Maven support (Maven dependencies container), using the standard Eclipse compiler and Run function.

Comment: A clever example would also include a copy of `foo()` and stick `@CompilerControl(DONT_LINE)` to clearly show the overhead of non-inlined call.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev You probably mean the insignificance of that overhead :) I'll add what you propose.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, that overhead is insignificant in hindsight :) This also omits a giant can of worms about inlining extending the scope of other optimizations; let's not go there!

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev About that point, does JMH itself know how to prevent inlining within its main measurement loop? I mean fusing the loop code with measured code. I also wonder what exactly that 1.279 ns in my measurement really pertains to, since the code is basically a no-op (returns a constant).

Comment: The methods with @Benchmark annotations are forcefully inlined, if that's what you are asking. Other answers are available with the help of perfasm. Ж)

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev Yes, that's basically my question and, particularly applied to this example, I see the entire method, which amounts to a compile-time constant, evaporating in the process, so I don't even see what the reported 1.279 ns should apply to, or how it would be derived. Maybe this is just the level which we should consider "noise" and take the measurement as saying "zero time taken".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: It is not "noise", think about this as the effect your measurement tool has on your measurement. It always helpful to estimate that effect, as in some cases it may become significant even though we are trying to get it as low as we can.

Answer (score 0):

*A note:* You can't measure time exactly enough for this kind of assumptions by just calling the method once. You'd have to at least do it multiple times to get a usable result.

Yes, calling a method is slower due to more instructions being involved. When the code is within the other function, it can simply be executed there. When a function is called, a new stack frame is created, and after returning removed. This takes a little time - at least until for example JIT kicks in and compiles said part. You should take a look at the [JVM specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html) for more information.